# How to apply a force that decays over time in solidworks simulation static

Tags: solidworks

I apply a force along the X coordinate. And I indicate the equation X + Y = 50

[image]

The graph of this equation is as follows

[image]

Do I understand correctly: the 50MPa strength will decrease to 0 over time?

I would greatly appreciate your help (P.S sorry for my English)

I tried to do a simulation. Everything works. But I don't know if the equation works. Now a force equal to 0MPa should be applied there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Applying Time Varying Force

1. Click on the down arrow below External Loads Advisor button in the Ribbon. List of the tools related to loads will be displayed
2. Click on the Force button from the list. The Force/Torque PropertyManager will be displayed
3. Note that Variation with Time rollout is added in the PropertyManager and two radio
   buttons are displayed named, Linear and Curve.